# Can I use gorilla schema with an sql.NullString?

Tags: sql, go, schema, gorilla

I am using gorilla schema to populate a struct based on a user's form submission. My struct contains `sql.NullString` and I am currently getting the following error:

`schema: converter not found for sql.NullString`

How can I use `sql.NullString` in a struct that I want to populate with gorilla schema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a gist ( https://gist.github.com/carbocation/51b55297702c7d30d3ef ) that shows one way to approach this. You need to create a `schema.Converter` for each of the four types: sql.NullString, sql.NullBool, sql.NullInt64, and sql.NullFloat64.

An example for sql.NullString:

```
import "database/sql"
import "reflect"

func ConvertSQLNullString(value string) reflect.Value {
    v := sql.NullString{}
    if err := v.Scan(value); err != nil {
        return reflect.Value{}
    }

    return reflect.ValueOf(v)
}
```

Then register this with your `*schema.Decoder` (usually a package global, in this case named `d`):

```
import "database/sql"

nullString := sql.NullString{}
d.RegisterConverter(nullString, ConvertSQLNullString)
```